# "I stop the game the first time I earn 100 dollars" is a stopping time but "The second time I earn 100 dollars" is not a stopping time, why?

Tags: probability, stopping-times

Let play a game : I toss a coin, and each time it get Head, I earn 10 dollars, and each time it get Tail, I loose 10 dollars. My teachers says :

*"I stop the game the first time I get 100 dollars"* is a stopping time since at each launch, I know If I earned 100 dollars or not, but *"I stop the game the second time I get 100 dollars"* is not a stopping time.

I don't understand why it's not a stopping time, because I also know at each launch if I already got twice 100 euros or not. So could someone give me more details ?

Comment: Determining that you got $100$ twice requires you to retain information about the past.  Of course, you can define that condition, but a great deal of the theory is devoted to Markov properties...those that do not require any memory of the past.

Comment: Are you sure that this is exactly what your teacher said...?

Comment: @saz : I'm quite sure. why, it's wrong ?

Comment: 2nd hitting time is a stopping time since you can write $(H_2=n)$ as a function of $(X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n)$.